# Lenovo Ideapad 330 MX150 Intel UHD 620 Prime video settings doesn't show any options

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo

So it's my first time using Ubuntu everything installed just fine and works...
But my video card doesn't show on Settings > About and i can only change Prime select to intel
If choose ON DEMAND my system does not boot at all
And I have massive screen tearing
Can anyone help?